# Construct non-trivial local martingale which is constant with positive probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

> Construct a continuous local martingale $(M(t))_{t \in [0,1]}$ with $M(0)=0$, $M(t)$ is not always equal to $0$, and $M(t)$ is constant with positive probability.

Is the above construction possible?

I am thinking that the $M(t)$ can divide as constant part and non-constant part, then I can show the positive part prob higher than 0.

However, I don't know how to find such.

Please provide me a example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$M(t)$ is constant with positive probability"...? Should the process satisfy $$\mathbb{P}(\forall t: M_t =M_0)>0$$ ...?

Comment: what alternative understanding？

Comment: Well, for instance that with probability $>0$ the sample path $M_t(\omega)$ is constant on some time interval ... or that there exists $c=c(t)>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(M_t=c)>0$.. whatsoever, there are plenty of possibilities. Obviously @Stefan didn't understand it the way you meant it.

Comment: sorry let me be clear.the word constant means that M(t,w)=M(0,w),t∈[0,1]

Comment: ... but then you can take any (local) martingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ starting at $X_0=0$ (e.g. a Brownian motion) and $$M_t := \begin{cases} 0, & t \leq 1, \\ X_{t-1}, & t>1 \end{cases}$$will do the job.

Comment: t>1 is not the range to be considered，so i dont understand the purpose.can you explain the above more in detail？

Comment: You didn't mention any range so I was assuming that you are talking about martingales $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with time index $t \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: oh come on，i  wrote clearly t∈[0,1]

Comment: Everything would be much clearer if you would format your question properly (=use MathJax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths (e.g. a Brownian motion), and let $X$ be a random variable which is independent from $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and which satisfies $$\mathbb{P}(X= 1) = \frac{1}{2} \qquad \mathbb{P}(X=0) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

If we consider

$$M_t := X \cdot B_t$$

with the filtration

$$\mathcal{F}_t := \sigma(X, B_s; s \leq t),$$

then $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has all desired properties. Clearly, $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, it satisfies $$\mathbb{P}(\forall t \geq 0: \, \, M_t=0)= \frac{1}{2},$$

and $(M_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale since

$$\mathbb{E}(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X \cdot \mathbb{E}(B_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X  \cdot B_s = M_s$$

for all $s \leq t$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $N\in exp(1)$ exponential distributed and consider the Brownian motion $W_t$ independant of $N$, and construct

$$
X_t = \int_N^t dW_{\tau}
$$

Hence 
$$
P(\{X_s\}_{s=0}^t \text{ is constant }) = P(N \geq t) > 0
$$

Also
$$
E(X_{t+s}|X_{t}) = P(N < t)E(X_{t+s}|X_{t},N<t)+ P(N \geq t)E(X_{t+s}|X_{t},N\geq)
$$
Now,
$$
E(X_{t+s}|X_{t},N\geq t) = \int E(\int_N^{t+s} dW_\tau|X_t=0,N > t,N=n)f_{N|N>t}(n) =\int 0 f_{N|N>t} = 0 = (X_t|N\geq t)
$$

and
$$
E(X_{t+s}|X_{t},N < t) = E(X_t+\int_t^{s+t}dW\tau|X_t,N<t) = X_t|N<t + 0
$$

hence we have
$$
E(X_{t+s}|X_{t}) = X_t
$$ becaus conditoin an both the events $N<t,N\geq t$ the expectation is $X_t$.

So this is a martingale and hence also a local martingale.

Answer (score 0):

An example without extra randomization would be $X_t=\int_0^t 1_{\{|W_s|\ge k\}}\,dW_s$, with $k$ a large constant. This is a local martingale (for $t\ge 0$, not just $t\in [0,1]$), and $X_t=0$ for $0\le t\le 1$ on the event $\{\max_{0\le s\le 1}|W(s)|<k\}$, which has probability close to 1 for $k$ large enough.